# CSS: slide left animation/transition without jquery

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a slide from right to left animation on hover of parent li (Programs in this case) The child ul should animate and open. I want to do it in css and which is supported all browsers ..

```
   .child
   {
    transition: 1s;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    top: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
   }
```

[My demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/6139405)

Comment: By all browser do you mean IE8 and below. Becuase ie8 does not support css3

Comment: @AnaMaria No support in IE9 either (iirc)

Comment: yeah i m talking about modern browsers..I dnt care in IE for time being

Comment: @user1145009, Check the solution i have posted

Comment: Yes it is. I cant begin to tell you how many hours i wasted of mine just cos all my code works in other browsers and doesnt work in IE. However we cannot force people to stop using it. As 12% of internet users still use IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your CSS a bit. This is not the complete solution. You will have to play around a bit to perfect it. but i think it pretty much is close to what you want to achieve.

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dMQgD/)

I will only add the CSS I made changes to.

```
.menu-1990:hover > .child {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:60px;
    height:auto;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-duration: 2s;

}
.child {
    transition: 1s;
    margin-left:0px;
    opacity:0;    
    height: 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;   

}
```

**EDIT:** Like i mentioned in my comment, this solution will only work with all browsers other than IE. Only IE10 supports the transition-duration property

Comment: Damn , this is the perfect answer .

Comment: @Anurag-Sharma, Thanks for the compliment

Answer (score 2):

Try JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2vLjU/50/

```
.wrapper:hover #slide {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I saw this example but in my case i have no div of fixed height width as shown in that example .. doesnt work for me ..

Comment: @user1145009 if you have other requirements to your question such as no `div` or fixed dimensions, you should add those details to your question.